# Twilio lookups and subaccounts

Tags: twilio

Does Twilio support lookup request using a subAccountSID instead of the accountSID?

I want this in order to organize the invoices for my clients and don't have to rely on creating my own log for that.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to use the subaccount details, you just need the subaccount sid and auth token. Then you can setup the lookups client like this:

```
const string subAccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const string subAuthToken = "subaccount_auth_token";
var lookupsClient = new LookupsClient(subAccountSid, subAuthToken);

// Look up a phone number in E.164 format
var phoneNumber = lookupsClient.GetPhoneNumber("+15108675309", true);
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed!!